# Rendering static webpage via github.io not working - for a website created with gatsby / hosted on netlify from a github repo

Tags: reactjs, github, yarnpkg, gatsby, netlify

I wanted to use a personal-website template for my github.io profile that I found at this link - https://github.com/bchiang7/v4 . I personalized it and hosted it on netlify.com at this link - https://objective-shannon-b564f7.netlify.com. On netlifly it looks perfect ! However when I downloaded the deploy-static files and rendered them via vidyabhandary.github.io - Part of the site is missing and the rest looks very odd.

The console errors indicate a json file, some font files and some resources are missing.

```
Uncaught Error: Missing resources for /
    at t.n.render (ensure-resources.js:135)
    at Oi (react-dom.production.min.js:173)
    at Ri (react-dom.production.min.js:172)
    at Mi (react-dom.production.min.js:180)
    at $a (react-dom.production.min.js:232)
    at Ka (react-dom.production.min.js:233)
    at Ol (react-dom.production.min.js:249)
    at Cl (react-dom.production.min.js:248)
    at kl (react-dom.production.min.js:245)
    at Ja (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
```

The font files and json are present in the directory path although there is a mismatch in the case (name).

I got no errors in the deploy on netlifly - only a warning that my logo.png was not square.

1. There was an warning previously in the netlifly deploy which stated that a peer dependency for gatsby was not met - so I added "webpack":"4.4.0" to my package.json file and that warning message is no longer present.

   warning "gatsby-plugin-netlify > webpack-assets-manifest@3.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=4.4.0"
2. I added a .nojekyll file
3. The static files do not change - whether I use - gatsby build / gatsby build; yarn build / yarn build.

Not sure what else I am missing.

```
'''
    11:18:43 AM: success Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles — 3.647 s
    11:18:44 AM: success Building static HTML for pages — 1.385 s — 4/4 11.30 pages/second
    11:18:44 AM: Generated public/sw.js, which will precache 10 files, totaling 472828 bytes.
    11:18:44 AM: info Done building in 8.671 sec

---

11:18:44 AM: Started saving node modules
11:18:44 AM: Finished saving node modules
11:18:44 AM: Started saving yarn cache
11:18:44 AM: Finished saving yarn cache
11:18:44 AM: Started saving pip cache
11:18:44 AM: Finished saving pip cache
11:18:44 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
11:18:44 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
11:18:44 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
11:18:44 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
11:18:44 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
11:18:44 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
11:18:44 AM: Started saving go dependencies
11:18:44 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
11:18:47 AM: Build script success
11:18:47 AM: Starting to deploy site from 'public/'
11:18:47 AM: Creating deploy tree 
11:18:47 AM: 0 new files to upload
11:18:47 AM: 0 new functions to upload
11:18:47 AM: Starting post processing
11:18:47 AM: Post processing done
11:18:48 AM: Site is live
11:19:15 AM: Finished processing build request in 1m57.314333898s
```

'''

Partial deploy log - which shows no errors.

Do I need to make changes of the folders that are present as part of the deployed files from netlifly ?

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/how-gatsby-works-with-github-pages/

Comment: As per that link - I added `"deploy": "gatsby build && gh-pages -d public -b master" ` to my package.json file and added in dev dependencies  `gh-pages`. However the static files generated are the same (I am downloading the created files and adding to the github.io site) and there are no changes in the files even after making these changes.

Comment: What about the bit about `pathprefix`?

Comment: The pathprefix is only if the website is being rendered through a /reponame - and not directly from *.github.io.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was recently patched in Gatsby v2.11.1. You can [see the full issue thread on Github here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11524).

Comment: I am using 2.3.x version of gatsby. Looks like a new issue is still to be raised for this.  (end of thread). Some of the other things mentioned in that thread - did not work yet !

Comment: @Vidya You can safely upgrade from 2.3.x to 2.11.1 unless you're relying on some specific internals. This error message was actually removed from the codebase when the relevant internals were refactored, which is to say it is impossible to get this error on 2.11.1.

Comment: And lest this seem like a lazy drive-by answer: I had been seeing this error on multiple projects all year until 2.11.1. I was fairly involved in the linked thread and getting the inkteam to realize the extent of the issue.

Comment: Awesome !! Thank you so much @coreyward !! That worked !! Now my github page is getting rendered ! Although the fonts are still not being found. So I guess that part is due to another reason - It still shows `HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - https://vidyabhandary.github.io/static/Calibre-Regular-b63c62e591d0c8fbe2c8f009883346d5.woff2` for many of the fonts. The fonts are present in that directory.

Comment: @Vidya Yeah I'm getting that 404 as well; maybe Github doesn't support serving `.woff2` files? Or it's just the wrong folder? Hard to say without seeing more details.

Comment: ttf, woff and woff2 files all are not being discovered. From the index.js file and tracing the path - it is present in the correct folder (static).  Looking at https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/6003 - the issue was not resolved and from https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2583 - other fonts were used instead.

Comment: Part of GlobalStyle.js `import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'; const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  `@font-face {
    font-family: 'Calibre';
    src: url(${fontFamilies.CalibreLightWOFF2}) format('woff2'),
    url(${fontFamilies.CalibreLightWOFF}) format('woff'),
    url(${fontFamilies.CalibreLightTTF}) format('truetype');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: auto;
  };` `export default GlobalStyle;`